# Java - Getting MAC address of Linux system

Tags: java, macos, crash, mac-address

I'm trying to get the MAC address of a linux system with this code:

```
try {
  ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
  byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
  // System.out.print("Current MAC address: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
    is = is + Integer.parseInt(
      String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "" : ""),16);
  }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SocketException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it just crashes... does anyone know why?

Comment: What error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/891wKcXz And yes, I have checked that it's this part. If I just put is = is + Integer.parseInt([mac address here],16); the code works fine

Comment: byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

Comment: The "system" does not have a MAC address.  A network interface does.  You can have multiple NICs in a single system and therefore multiple MAC addresses as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, clearly `network` is `null`, which means that `getByInetAddress()` could not find an interface with that IP address (see the JavaDocs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getByInetAddress(java.net.InetAddress)).

Comment: -facepalm, did NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0"); and it worked instantly. Thanks heaps :D

Comment: FYI http://www.includehelp.com/java-programs/get-system-mac-address-of-windows-or-linux-machine.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You might have more than one network interface and I would not count on the interface's name. I suggest you to go over all the interfaces and look for one that has a MAC address.
You can use this example as a base line:

```
try {

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements())
        {
            NetworkInterface network = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println("network : " + network);
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            if(mac == null)
            {
                System.out.println("null mac");             
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("MAC address : ");

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
                {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());  
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small modification of the code of Guy :

```
public String searchForMac() throws SocketException {
    String firstInterface = null;        
    Map<String, String> addressByNetwork = new HashMap<>();
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

    while(networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()){
        NetworkInterface network = networkInterfaces.nextElement();

        byte[] bmac = network.getHardwareAddress();
        if(bmac != null){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bmac.length; i++){
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", bmac[i], (i < bmac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }

            if(sb.toString().isEmpty()==false){
                addressByNetwork.put(network.getName(), sb.toString());
                System.out.println("Address = "+sb.toString()+" @ ["+network.getName()+"] "+network.getDisplayName());
            }

            if(sb.toString().isEmpty()==false && firstInterface == null){
                firstInterface = network.getName();
            }
        }
    }

    if(firstInterface != null){
        return addressByNetwork.get(firstInterface);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code has been tested on Windows, Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac OS X with success.

Because the network can be null, I ignore all null cases and I also ignore empty addresses. I think that if we don't do this, we view the crash. I choose the first found address and it works but it may be wrong, so just test it.